# What is the guarantee for little-o to be a strict upper bound?

Tags: little-o

Whether the little-o is tight upper bound or strict upper bound?

Correct the answer below if wrong,

`g(x)` is an upper bound for `f(x)` that is not asymptotically tight.
There is a much larger gap between the growth rates of `f and g` if `f ∈ o(g)` than if `f ∈ O(g)`.

Big-O is to little-o as ≤ is to <. big-O is an inclusive upper bound, while little-o is a strict upper bound.

Isn't it enough to guarantee a strict upper bound?

Comment: This might be one for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition looks correct, but I am not sure about your use of terms.

From Wikipedia: [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) vs [little-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations)

> In this way, little-o notation makes a stronger statement than the corresponding big-O notation: every function that is little-o of g is also big-O of g, but not every function that is big-O of g is also little-o of g (for instance g itself is not, unless it is identically zero near ∞).

Another useful quote:

> the relation f(x) = o(g(x)) is equivalent to
>   lim(f(x)/g(x)) = 0 (when x -> ∞)
>   vs
>   the relation f(x) = O(g(x)) is equivalent to
>   lim(f(x)/g(x)) < ∞ (when x -> ∞)